High school comedy drama about a brother and sister that join a new school
I remember most scenes very clearly.
The brother is a runner and in this new school he befriends a nerd (?) girl with greasy hair (which is mentioned several times in the movie). 
I don't remember much about the sis but I distinctly remember that she has a Michael Jackson​ poster in her room that she worships. 
Basically the brother wins the final race in the movie where he is congratulated by a lot of people including his sister, after a couple of failures and when the popular hot girl is finally interested in him and asks to be in a relationship, he says "Of course...... NOT". During the pause between the 'of course' and 'not', the greasy nerdy girl walks away, visibly upset. The guy goes back get the greasy haired girl and after he explains everything, they make out, which concludes the movie.
At least, that's what I remember. This movie is most probably from the 2000s. Probably mid-to-late era. 
Note that there are the expected antagonists, the jock that's also a runner but he's better than him (until the end), the hot popular girl I mentioned (probably a cheerleader). And there's an entire arc focusing on his sister which I can't seem to remember. Also, during their make out scene at the end, the brother says "Let's go get your hair fixed" or something along those lines.

Some Sum41 and beer and we have a 90's classic !

I see someone suggested the VH1 movie Totally Awesome on reddit; it sounds like a pretty safe bet.
